# typing error, trying to display something onclick in TSX but getting undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend, antd

I have a table setup through Ant Design, and am trying to grab information through my parent component onclick. I have made a handleclick function to do the dirtywork, and want to call this onclick. VSCode tells me it recognizes the "record" object through the call, but it still returns "undefined". Probably a simple mistake, any ideas why this happen?

setName is a react hooks function passed down from parent, for reference. The code below is an omitted section for increased readability

My code:

```
const handleClick = ({ record, setSchemaName }: any) => {
    console.log('record is:' + record);
    message.info('Du har valgt Skjema ' + record.id);
    setSchemaName(record.schemaName);

// ....

<Table
                        key={response.id + 40}
                        style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
                        size="small"
                        columns={columns}
                        dataSource={dataSource}
                        pagination={{ pageSize: 8 }}
                        onRow={(record) => ({
                            onClick: () => handleClick(record),
                        })}
                    />

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid using `any` when you're not sure about typing.
As I see

```
onRow={(record) => ({
  onClick: () => handleClick(record),
})}
```

you give `record` to `handleClick`.

So

```
const handleClick = ({ record, setSchemaName }: any) => {
```

should be

```
const handleClick = (record: YourRecordType, setSchemaName: OtherType) => {
```

Please note that:

- you really should avoid using `any` when typing is valuable,
- `setSchemaName` needs to be passed to `handleClick`, in `onRow` (as I see)

I hope it helps you !

Comment: Thank you for the tips. The reason we are using any, is due to this being our very first TS project, so we are unsure how and where to declare stuff, as evident by this post. Thank you!